# Running certbot-auto without being root

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm running into permissions issues renewing my certs with certbot-auto, because whenever it runs it displays this message:

```
Requesting to rerun certbot-auto with root privileges...
```

There is no need for it to run as root, because the user running the command has permissions on all directories used by certbot.  I couldn't find any command-line options to disable this, but looking at the script itself I discovered that when it re-runs itself it checks for the argument 
`--cb-auto-has-root` and if it's there it doesn't try to obtain root (again).  I found that if I run certbot-auto with this command it runs just fine as non-root!

But I'm not sure if this workaround should be used - since it's undocumented - or will break in the future.  What's the recommended way to run as a non-root user?